# Difference Between EffectiveRange and LongestEffectiveRange

Tags: objective-c, attributes, range, nsattributedstring

In the `NSAttributedString` class, there are functions that get the values of attributes for certain indices and ranges but I'm unsure of the difference between the selectors `attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange` and `attributesAtIndex:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:` and when would I use one instead of the other? Thanks in advance for any clarification

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say you have this kind of attributes:
Range [0,2]: Black Background Color
Range [0,2]: Bold Font
Range [2,4]: Black Background Color
Range [2,4]: Italic Font

If you log this `NSAttributedString`, its attributes will be separated in two:
Range [0,2]: Black Background Color AND Bold Font
Range [2,4]: Black Background Color AND Italic Font
These attributes works like a `NSDictionary`, they are 2 different at two ranges.

If you use `longestEffectiveRange` at index 0 for `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName`, you'll get a range of [0,4].
If you use `effectiveRange`, you'll get [0,2].
In other words, the `longestEffectiveRange` will check if there is on the next index (after the end of `effectiveRange`) that may have another dictionary of attributes if it shares the wanted value with it and then append the range.

Sample Code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"BoBiBu"];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor blackColor]
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                         value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                         value:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12]
                         range:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor blackColor]
                         range:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
NSLog(@"AttributedString: %@", attributedString);


NSRange range1;
NSLog(@"Attribute: %@", [attributedString attribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName atIndex:0 effectiveRange:&range1]);
NSLog(@"EffectiveRange of previous attribute: %@", NSStringFromRange(range1));

NSRange range2;
NSLog(@"Attribute: %@", [attributedString attribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName atIndex:0 longestEffectiveRange:&range2 inRange:NSMakeRange(0, 6)]);
NSLog(@"Longest effective Range of previous attribute: %@", NSStringFromRange(range2));
```

Logs:

```
> AttributedString: Bo{
    NSBackgroundColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd3e2f80ec0> font-family: \".HelveticaNeueInterface-MediumP4\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
}Bi{
    NSBackgroundColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd3e2f83310> font-family: \".HelveticaNeueInterface-Italic\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-size: 12.00pt";
}Bu{
}
> Attribute: UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1
> EffectiveRange of previous attribute: {0, 2}
> Attribute: UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1
> Longest effective Range of previous attribute: {0, 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a test for complementing the best answer.

```swift
// In UnitTest target.

func testLongestEffectiveRange() throws {

    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: "abcd")
    textStorage.addAttributes([.backgroundColor: UIColor.red, .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 2))
    textStorage.addAttributes([.backgroundColor: UIColor.red, .font: UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 17)], range: NSRange(location: 2, length: 2))

    var effectiveColorRange: NSRange? = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
    let effectiveColor = textStorage.attribute(.backgroundColor, at: 0, effectiveRange: &effectiveColorRange!)
    XCTAssertEqual(effectiveColorRange, NSRange(location: 0, length: 2))
    XCTAssertEqual((effectiveColor as? UIColor), UIColor.red)

    var effectiveFontRange: NSRange? = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
    let effectiveFont = textStorage.attribute(.font, at: 0, effectiveRange: &effectiveFontRange!)
    XCTAssertEqual(effectiveFontRange, NSRange(location: 0, length: 2))
    XCTAssertEqual((effectiveFont as? UIFont), UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17))

    var longestEffectiveColorRange: NSRange? = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
    let longestEffectiveColor = textStorage.attribute(.backgroundColor, at: 2, longestEffectiveRange: &longestEffectiveColorRange!, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: textStorage.string.utf16.count))

    // longestEffectiveRange returns the longest possible range for the attribute.
    XCTAssertEqual(longestEffectiveColorRange, NSRange(location: 0, length: 4))
    XCTAssertEqual((longestEffectiveColor as? UIColor), UIColor.red)

    var longestEffectiveFontRange: NSRange? = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
    let longestEffectiveFont = textStorage.attribute(.font, at: 2, effectiveRange: &longestEffectiveFontRange!)
    XCTAssertEqual(longestEffectiveFontRange, NSRange(location: 2, length: 2))
    XCTAssertEqual((longestEffectiveFont as? UIFont), UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 17))

}
```