# NSMutableAttributedString: How do I retrieve attributes over a range

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I have set up a simple playground to demonstrate my problem in retrieving the attributes of attributed strings.  Perhaps I do not understand how to define ranges:  perhaps I am missing something else.

I have define a NSMutableAttributedString that has two colors in it as well as a change in font to bold(for the blue) and italic(for the red):

```
var someText =  NSMutableAttributedString()

let blueAttri : [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue]
let redAttri : [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]

someText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some blue string here; ", attributes: blueAttri)
someText.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some red string here; ", attributes: redAttri))
```

At this point the string looks fine showing text with both colors.

I then have defined 3 ranges (attempting different approaches to defining ranges.)

```
var range1 = NSRange()
var range2 = NSRange(location: 0, length: someText.length)
var range3 = NSRange(location: 40, length: 44)
```

Lastly, I try to retrieve attributes for the text

```
// retrieve attributes
let attributes1 = someText.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: &range1)

// iterate each attribute
print("attributes1")
for attr in attributes1 {
    print(attr.key, attr.value)
}

let attributes2 = someText.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: &range2)

// iterate each attribute
print("attributes2")
for attr in attributes2 {
    print(attr.key, attr.value)
}


let attributes3 = someText.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: &range3)

// iterate each attribute
print("attributes3")
for attr in attributes3 {
    print(attr.key, attr.value)
}
```

I get the following results.  In all cases showing only the first set of attributes.

attributes1
NSAttributedStringKey(_rawValue: NSColor) UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1
  NSAttributedStringKey(_rawValue: NSFont)  font-family: ".SFUIText-Semibold"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt

attributes2
NSAttributedStringKey(_rawValue: NSColor) UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1 
NSAttributedStringKey(_rawValue: NSFont)  font-family: ".SFUIText-Semibold"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt

attributes3
NSAttributedStringKey(_rawValue: NSColor) UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1
NSAttributedStringKey(_rawValue: NSFont)  font-family: ".SFUIText-Semibold"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt

What do I need to do to get all of the attributes in the string?

It has been suggested I use enumerate attributes.  That does not seem to be legal.  See below:
[image]

Comment: It's the `attributes(at:, effectiveRange:)` method that you didn't understand. It take the attributes at the place `at`, and with effectiveRange, that's something else. So at 0, for the first two tries, you get the same, that's normal. To get all the attributes, use `enumerateAttributes(in:options:using:)` where you set the range from 0 to the length.

Comment: enumerateAttributes does not appear possible.  Please see image added above.

Comment: It's possible. Try it. But it doesn't return a value.

Comment: It doesn't return anything, that's why it's not allowed in your case. You can't do `let attribute4 = someText.enumerateAttributes(in:options:using:)`, but you can do `someText.enumerateAttributes(in:options:using:)`

Comment: Also, that's in Objective-C, but logic is the same (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297969/difference-between-effectiverange-and-longesteffectiverange) but the `range` parameter is a pointer, meaning you don't put value in it, it will have afterwards the range corresponding.

Comment: Larme, I see now that it does not return.  I missed that.  Working on how I can use it -- adding to my Swift skills.

Answer (score 7):

Using `enumerateAttributes` I was able to capture ranges with Italic (just to show one example).  The following is the complete code:

```
//Create Empty Dictionaries for storing results
var attributedFontRanges = [String: UIFont]()
var attributedColorRanges = [String: UIColor]()

//Find all attributes in the text.
someText.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: someText.length)) { (attributes, range, stop) in

    attributes.forEach { (key, value) in
        switch key {

        case NSAttributedString.Key.font:
            attributedFontRanges[NSStringFromRange(range)] = value as? UIFont

        case NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:
            attributedColorRanges[NSStringFromRange(range)] = value as? UIColor

        default:

            assert(key == NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, "Unknown attribute found in the attributed string")
        }
}
}

//Determine key(range) of Italic font
var italicRange = attributedFontRanges.filter { $0.value.fontName == ".SFUIText-Italic" }.keys

print("italicRange: \(italicRange)")
```

The following results are printed:
italicRange: ["{23, 22}"]

Comment: You need to change `someText.length` to `someText.utf16.count`.

Comment: Reading from documentation [link] (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1418432-length) it appears length is the number of utf-16 units: "_The number of UTF-16 code units in the receiver._"

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I kept thinking you were getting the length of a Swift `String`, not an `NSAttributedString`. I've helped with a few questions where people were trying to create ranges based on `String` length, and then use that range with `NSAttributedString`. So your code should be good.

Comment: Thanks, super helpful solution... exactly what I was needing

Answer (score 1):

You are using `attributes` with the same `at:` value of `0` for all three calls. That returns the attributes for the 1st character in the string.

If you want all of the attributes in a range, use `enumerateAttributes` and pass in the range you want to iterate over.

Note: The range you pass needs to be based on the UTF-16 encoding of the string, not the Swift string length. Those two lengths can be different when you have special characters such as Emojis. Using `NSAttributedString length` is fine.

Comment: I read the note, but apparently I didn’t interpret correctly.  Did I define range wrong?  How should I define range?