# Get the range of a paragraph NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I would like to be able to get the range(s) of the paragraph(s) overlapping with the textView.selectedRange.

My goal is to change the alignment of the whole paragraph where the selection is.

I have tried the following but the ranges provided by enumerate attribute seem to all be of length 1, making my intersection check useless.

Is there a way to get a list of continuous ranges with the same paragraph style?

```
var alignment: NSTextAlignment

let contentRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: editor.contentLength)

editor.attributedText.enumerateAttribute(.paragraphStyle, in: contentRange, options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { (paragraphStyle, range, _) in
    
    //Check if attribute range contains cursor
    if NSIntersectionRange(range, editor.selectedRange).length > 0 {
        print(range)
        if let paragraphStyle = paragraphStyle as? NSParagraphStyle {
            let newStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle.mutableParagraphStyle
            newStyle.alignment = alignment
            
            editor.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: newStyle, at: range)
        }
    } 
}
```

Many thanks

#### Edit

Thanks to @Larme, having no options does indeed get a continuous range:
`editor.attributedText.enumerateAttribute(.paragraphStyle, in: contentRange, options: []) { (paragraphStyle, range, _) in`

However, this will combine consecutive paragraphs with the same paragraph style in the same range.

i.e.

1. The user creates three paragraphs aligned to the left
2. The user wants to change the middle one to align right
3. They should be able to
   a) select any portion of the paragraph
   b) have the cursor at any position in the paragraph (selection length 0) to achieve the same result (*affecting the whole paragraph*)
4. The current check using `enumarateAttribute` will return a range grouping all three paragraphs together (as they all have the same paragraphStyle) and apply the new alignment to all of them.

*The `enumerateAttribute` doesn't really get the range of a single paragraph it will return a consecutive range for all consecutive paragraphs with the same paragraphStyle*

**Is there another way to get the range of the paragraph corresponding to the selectedRange?**

Comment: `longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired` use no option. Imagine that you first char is with font effect1 and paragraph effect 2, second char is with font effect 3 and paragraphe effect2. With your method you'll get two hits, one per letter, while with no option, it will find only one paragraph style, for both letters.

Comment: It seems that values might have changed, but check the naming, it's the same logic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297969/difference-between-effectiverange-and-longesteffectiverange/32305553#32305553

Comment: @Larme Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for however my logic was flawed. This will encapsulate **all paragraphs** with the same paragraph style in the same range. Hence, applying the alignment to all of them even if the cursor position is not located in the paragraph. I'll have to come up with a better way to detect the cursor's paragraph. Any ideas?

Comment: `in: contentRange`, instead use the `editor.selectedRange` ;) Then, instead of `editor.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: newStyle, at: range)`, use ``editor.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: newStyle, at: NSIntersectionRange(range, editor.selectedRange)`, that should do the trick, no?`

Comment: @Larme. As I understand it, that would only apply the `newStyle` to the attributedString within the `selectedRange`. I would like to apply the `newStyle` across the whole paragraph even if the selectedRange has `length = 0` (i.e. just a cursor) or if the selectedRange is only a portion of the full paragraph. I am trying to mimic the behaviour of alignment changing in standard rich text editors. (Word etc.)

Comment: Ah, I musunderstood, I thought you wanted to modify only for the selected one, then, just removing the `longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired` option doesn't work? I don't understand the `However, this will add consecutive paragraphs with the same paragraph style in the same range.` issue.

Comment: Ah, I musunderstood, I thought you wanted to modify only for the selected one, then, just removing the `longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired` option doesn't work? I don't understand the `However, this will add consecutive paragraphs with the same paragraph style in the same range. issue. `, could it be that you want to apply it on NSUnionRange (of both found range AND selected range)?

Comment: @Larme, Thanks. I've added more info in the edit. And I don't want the union, I wan't it to apply to the whole range of the paragraph.

Comment: Ok. I'd say that from the selectedRange, you'd have to find yourself the paragraph, looking for "\n": previous one and next one.

Comment: @Larme Yep that sounds like the best option. I'll get working on it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: There are unmanaged edges cases, but that could be a start (you can use that in Playground: https://pastebin.com/0EVTyLaD)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but hopefully this helps.

The way I approached this problem was by saving the selected range, pulling an NSString from my NSAttributedString, then calling NSString's paragraphRange. Once you have the paragraph range, then you can enumerate however you'd like!

```
//0: SAVE RANGE

let rangeOfNote = yourTextView.selectedRange


//1: CONVERT NSATTRIBUTEDSTRING TO NSSTRING

let composeText = yourTextView.attributedText.string as NSString


//2: CALL NSSTRING'S PARAGRAPH RANGE (for: NSRange)

let paragraphRange = composeText.paragraphRange(for: rangeOfNote)


//3: CHECK CORRECT
    
print(composeText.substring(with: paragraphRange), paragraphRange)

//4: Use range in enumerate attributes.

yourTextView.attributedText.enumerateAttributes(in: paragraphRange, ...)
```